# Rename the sub-total line

Tags: commerce

currently on my orders, I have the line "sub-total". How to change the name to "subtotal without promotions" ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a custom module using the `hook_commerce_price_component_type_info_alter` hook.

*Remember to replace HOOK with your module name.*

```
function HOOK_commerce_price_component_type_info_alter(&$component_types) {
  $component_types['base_price']['display_title'] = t('Subtotal without promotions');
}
```